# How to rewrite text in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface

I'm having a problem refreshing text on a timer. I am displaying the current time and refreshing the screen every second. The problem I'm having is the old time doesn't get erased when the new time gets printed.

Here is the function that displays the current time.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGPoint location = CGPointMake(10,20);
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSDate date]];
    [s drawAtPoint:location withFont:font];
}
```

Here is the timer that refreshes the current time every second:

```
- (IBAction)startRepeatingTimer {
    NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [runloop addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

How can I erase the old text or wipe the whole screen clean?

Comment: Any particular reason your not just using a label? You usually don't draw text that has to be constantly redrawn. It's easier to use one of the text centric UI elements instead.

Comment: I'm just experimenting with cocoa and was wondering how to do it by hand. I planned on using interface builder before releasing any apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you draw text into a context, its no longer text but just another graphical pattern in the bits. You're basically stuck with overwriting the drawn text with the background color. If you have a complex background, you can copy it before drawing the text and then draw the copy in the same position over and over again to erase.

However, you probably shouldn't bother. It's almost always easier and more robust to use an interface element designed to display text such as a label.

Answer (score 0):

I found one technique that works.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```